# How can I pass a base64 string as a parameter of a Python script?

Tags: python, bash, image, base64, vision

I am trying to pass as a parameter in a python script a string in base 64.

I'm using Pycharm, and when I try to send it as a parameter I get the following:

***Error running 'preprocess_image': Cannot run program "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" (in directory "...."): CreateProcess error=206, Filename or extension is too long***

It's logical, because base64 string is too big.

I'm tried using bash, but when i execute:

```
python preprocess_image.py --image base64String
```

This return nothing....

I've been looking for a while and I have not found any solution...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the base64 string in a file, and pass that filename to your python script.

Or you could pass it via stdin :

```
import sys
print(sys.stdin.readlines())

# echo "hello" | python preprocess_image.py
# => ['hello\n']
```

Comment: First solution is not appropiate for my problem, but the second is really good! Thank you, its working!